# JsonParserException while trying to read json file

Tags: java, json, jackson

Book.json

```
[{
"title": "Hunger Games",
"description": " fast paced In a not-too-distant future, the United States of America has collapsed, weakened by drought, fire, famine, and war, to be replaced by Panem, a country divided into the Capitol and 12 districts. Each year, two young representatives from each district are selected by lottery to participate in The Hunger Games. Part entertainment, part brutal intimidation of the subjugated districts, the televised games are broadcast throughout Panem as the 24 participants are forced to eliminate their competitors, literally, with all citizens required to watch. When 16-year-old Katniss s young sister, Prim, is selected as the mining district s female representative, Katniss volunteers to take her place. She and her male counterpart, Peeta, the son of the town baker who seems to have all the fighting skills of a lump of bread dough, will be pitted against bigger, stronger representatives who have trained for this their whole lives. Collins s characters are completely realistic and sympathetic as they fight and form alliances literary distant future great man and friendships in the face of distant future overwhelming odds; the plot is tense, dramatic, and engrossing. This book will definitely resonate with the generation raised on reality shows like Survivor and American Gladiator. Book one of a planned trilogy."
```

}]

```
public class FileReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String keywordCsv= "resources/addresses.csv";
    String booksJson ="resources/books.json";
    //Csvfilereader.processBySplit(fileName);
    Csvfilereader csvReader= new Csvfilereader();
    //ReadJson readjson =new ReadJson();
    ObjectMapper csvobj;
    ObjectMapper descriptionJsonobj=new ObjectMapper() ;
    MapType type = descriptionJsonobj.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(
            Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
    try {
        csvobj= csvReader.processByStreamApi(keywordCsv);
        Map<String,Object> jsonMap = descriptionJsonobj.readValue(booksJson, type);
        jsonMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println((k +": "+ v)));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    System.out.println("Successfull");
    //JsonObjectFormatVisitor

}
```

}

After running the program following exception is giving

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'resources': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (String)"resources/books.json"; line: 1, column: 10]
Successfull
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:703)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2853)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1899)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:757)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3042)
    at com.readcsv.FileReader.main(FileReader.java:28)
```

I am new in java. I have to match keword from csv file with books.json file. I am using jackson ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 4):

```
String booksJson ="resources/books.json";
```

is just a string that represents probably a path to your file. You are passing this string to object mapper - and this string is not a valid json. ObjectMapper's readValue method,that you are using, expects first argument to be a valid json.

Here

```
descriptionJsonobj.readValue(booksJson, type);
```

bookJson should be a valid json and currently it is not because you assigned it value "resources/books.json".

You should load your file content into some String variable, for example using Java 8 Files class or whatever. Then when you load your file content into some string variable just pass it to ObjectMapper's readValue method.

Comment: Yess I have to use new File() in objectmapper thanks. I have missed that